# R: Unused argument "label" in hclust

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm using the following code to build and hierarchical cluster:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection("
pdb      PA      EHSS 
1avd_model.pdb  3028.0  3920.0
1ave_model.pdb  3083.0  4019.0
1ij8_model.pdb  2958.0  3830.0
1ldo_model.pdb  2889.0  3754.0
1ldq_model.pdb  2758.0  3590.0
1lel_model.pdb  2815.0  3650.0
1vyo_model.pdb  2877.0  3740.0
2a5b_model.pdb  3145.0  4103.0
2a5c_model.pdb  3072.0  3994.0
2a8g_model.pdb  3056.0  3978.0
2avi_model.pdb  2856.0  3700.0
2c4i_model.pdb  2934.0  3795.0
2cam_model.pdb  3112.0  4053.0
2jgs.pdb    2913.0  3739.0
3fdc_model.pdb  2837.0  3666.0"), header=TRUE)

d <- dist(dat$PA, method = "euclidean")
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward", labels=dat$pdb)
plot(fit)
```

But when it build the cluster I get the following error message `unused argument(s) (labels = dat$pdb)`.

Why isn't labels working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`hclust` doesn't take a `labels` argument ... but its plot method does.  Try this to see:

```
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward")
plot(fit, labels=dat$pdb)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because `hclust` doesn't have a `labels` argument...

```
> args(hclust)
function (d, method = "complete", members = NULL) 
NULL
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Comment: it does according to this http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/hclust.html

Comment: No it doesn't (even though a `labels` argument does appear on that help page.  That's because the help page documents three different functions -- `hclust`, `plot` (actually `plot.hclust`, the plotting method for `hclust` objects), and `plclust`. If you look in the `Usage` section, you'll see that `hclust()` itself only takes three arguments, none of them `label`.

Comment: @Harpal - Well, I have R 2.14.0, and it obviously does not have a labels arg - so the documentation must be wrong then... `args` don't lie ;-)